# Google Place iOS SDK 3.0.2 - Getting Error when upload to iTunes

Tags: google-places-api

Getting below error when uploading archive to Apple iTunes with Google Place SDK 3.0.2.

Xcode 9.4.1

> "ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at
>   'Payload/.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/Assets.car'
>   can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and
>   frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
For me it failed to upload from ApplicationLoader but it worked when uploading directly from Xcode. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Able to upload build in Apple Store using XCode 10 with newer Google iOS SDK 3.0.2.

I was able to build app & run in device using XCode 9.4.1, it don't give any error. But you won't able to upload to TestFlight or Apple Store.